# Clients to read/respond to StackOverflow beyond the main web site

Tags: discussion, client

I was wondering if there are any OSX/Linux/Windows applications (air, widgets, etc...) or iPhone/Android applications that you would recommend. I have come out empty handed with computer clients, and am not satisfied with the existing cell phone applications..
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you just listed five completely separate categories, but you can check the corresponding tags on [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/) to find clients for each platform